# Plotting International Date Line on OSM android map

Tags: android, drawing, openstreetmap

I want to draw the international date line on an OSM map on android. Is there any way to do this? If yes, then how?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what accuracy level you need, but I only found this [website](http://ithoughthecamewithyou.com/post/International-Date-Line-Longitude-Latitude-Coordinates.aspx) providing lat/lon coordinates of the line based on the digitisation of the corresponding Wikipedia image... This is at least something.

You would then need a framework for adding vector data to your OSM map on Android. On desktop PCs, [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) is the best choice. You can also try to [bring OpenLayers to your phone](http://mobilegeo.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/testing-open-layers-with-iphone-and-android/), however, this seems to be not really well established yet. Maybe what you want to do can be achieved with a less-comprehensive framework. You might want to have a look at [existing Android OSM apps](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android), which partly support the display of .gpx tracks.

Best, Matthias